# MongoDB Query building is not working as expected in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, algorithm, logic

I am trying to build a MongoDB query based on OR and AND but having difficulties in making query logic, **for every OR word between keywords, the keywords need to go in the Should block, and for AND between words it needs to go in the must block.**

---

**example -**

1. keyword1 OR keyword2 => both will go in should block.
2. keyword1 And keyword2 => both will go in the must block.
3. keyword1 OR keyword2 AND keyword3=> keyword1, keyword2 will go in
   the should block, keyword3 will go in must block.

---

**Should query:**

```
    [{
  "$search": {
      "index": "fulltext",
      "compound": {
          "should": [{
              "text": {
                  "query": keyword1,
                  "path": ["headline"]
              }
          }]
      }
  }
}]
```

**Must Query:**

```
    [{
  "$search": {
      "index": "fulltext",
      "compound": {
          "must": [{
              "text": {
                  "query": keyword1,
                  "path": ["headline"]
              }
          }]
      }
  }
}]
```

Now for every New keyword which is >1 in both must and should, logic needs to add 1 new text block with comma separated.

```
                  "text": {
                  "query": new-keyword,
                  "path": ["headline"]
              }
```

and the whole query**(sytax same only needs to change must/should based on requirements)** looks like this for 2 keywords:

```
    [{
  "$search": {
      "index": "fulltext",
      "compound": {
          "should": [{
              "text": {
                  "query": keyword1,
                  "path": ["headline"]
              }
          }, {
              "text": {
                  "query": new-keyword,
                  "path": ["headline"]
              }
          }]
      }
  }
}]
```

**in my case, for Should it is working fine but for must it is not working as expected or as I explained above**

**Current Code -**

**payloads examples:**

1. keyword1 and keyword2 = > `['keyword1', 'AND', 'keyword2']`
2. keyword1 or keyword2 = > `['keyword1', 'OR', 'keyword2']`
3. keyword1 or keyword2 AND Keyword3 = > `['keyword1', 'OR', 'keyword2', 'AND', 'Keyword3']`

   ```
     const getArticles = (req, res) => {
   const _searchKeyword = req.body.groupkeyword;
   const keywords = _searchKeyword.replace(/[()]/g, "").toUpperCase().split(" ");
   let agg;
   const mustArray = [];
   const shouldArray = [];


   if (keywords.length === 1) {
   //some other logic
   } else {
     let currentArray = shouldArray;
     for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
       if (keywords[i] === "OR") {
         currentArray = shouldArray;
       } else if (keywords[i] === "AND") {
         currentArray = mustArray;
       } else {
         currentArray.push({
           text: {
             query: keywords[i],
             path: ["headline"],
           },
         });
       }
     }

     if (mustArray.length > 0 || shouldArray.length > 0) {
       agg = [
         {
           $search: {
             index: "fulltext",
             compound: {
               must: mustArray,
               should: shouldArray,
             },
           },
         }
       ];
     }
   }

   searchModel.aggregate(agg, (err, data) => {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       res.status(500);
     } else {
       const _articleids = data.map((x) => x.articleid);
       res.status(200);
       res.json(_articleids);
     }
   });
   };
   ```

Comment: could you log `agg` and check if `mustArray` exist? according to looping, `mustArray` will be empty if `OR` present.

Comment: according to the current code if I type - keyword1 and keyword2 then it will result in - 

`[{"$search":{"index":"fulltext","compound":{"must":[{"text":{"query":"keyword2","path":["headline"]}}],"should":[{"text":{"query":"keyword1","path":["headline"]}}]}}}]` **which is totally wrong it should be like**  - `[{"$search":{"index":"fulltext","compound":{"must":[{"text":{"query":"keyword2","path":["headline"]}},{"text":{"query":"keyword2","path":["headline"]}}]}}}]`

Comment: oke, could you also put an example of your payload in `keywords`?

Comment: payload - keyword1 and keyword2 = > `['keyword1', 'AND', 'keyword2']`

Comment: then the problem was in the condition `if`. and you can optimize the condition `else` to be ```else{
 if (keywords.indexOf('AND') > 0) currentArray = mustArray;
  if (keywords.indexOf('OR') > 0) currentArray = shouldArray;

}```

Comment: update, i forget the AND with OR 
```
else{
  let keywords = ['keyword1','AND', 'keyword2']
  if (keywords.indexOf('AND') > 0) currentArray = mustArray //handle query here instead;
  else if(keywords.indexOf('OR') > 0) currentArray = shouldArray //handle query here instead;
  else if (keywords.indexOf('OR') > 0 && keywords.indexOf('AND') > 0) currentArray = shouldArray//handle query here instead;  
}
```

Comment: @TobokSitanggang, it seems confusing could you please write in answer section rather than comment with context to my previous code, it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: yeah, sure, put the code snippet inside `else` and remove unnecessary variables. i used them as just for POC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let keywords = ['keyword1','OR', 'keyword2', 'AND', 'keyword4']
let mustArray = [];
let shouldArray = [];

const setupQuery = (keywords) => {
  const query = [];

  keywords.forEach((keyword) => {
    if (keyword !== "AND" || keyword !== "OR") {
      query.push({
        text: {
          query: keyword,
          path: ["headline"],
        },
      });
    }
  });
  return query.filter(
    (el) => el.text.query !== "AND" && el.text.query !== "OR"
  );
};

if (keywords.indexOf("AND") >= 0 && keywords.indexOf("OR") <= -1) mustArray = setupQuery(keywords);
else if (keywords.indexOf("OR") >= 0 && keywords.indexOf("AND") <= -1) shouldArray = setupQuery(keywords);
else if (keywords.indexOf("OR") >= 0 && keywords.indexOf("AND") >= 0) {
  const newQuery = setupQuery(keywords)
  shouldArray = newQuery.slice(0, 2);
  mustArray = newQuery.slice(2);
}

console.log('mustArray', JSON.stringify(mustArray));
console.log('shouldArray', JSON.stringify(shouldArray));
```